# Print the last character of a string in mips

Tags: assembly, mips

I have this code that should print the last character of a string

```
.data 

prompt:             .asciiz "Please enter a string :\n"
buffer:         .space 1024


.text
.globl main

main:

print_prompt:   li $v0, 4
                la $a0, prompt
                syscall
                li $v0, 8           #read text from user as text            
                la $a0, buffer
                li $a1, 255
                syscall



 la $t1,buffer 


 loop: 
 lb $t2,($t1) 
 beq $t2,$zero,loop1 
 add $t1,$t1,1 
 j loop

loop1:
sub $t1,$t1,1
lb $a0,($t1)
li $v0,11
syscall 

li $v0,10 
syscall
```

im doing the beq $t2,$zero,loop1 to check if the string has ended it should equal to zero, or is that wrong? I tried changing this to beq $t2,'?',loop1 for example and entered the character '?' in the input and that worked fine it printed the last character before the '?'

Comment: Does the user input get NUL-terminated?

Comment: You `lb` from `$t1`, increment `$t1` unconditionally, and if the value you loaded was zero, you decrement `$t1`. Would you like to guess where `$t1` points to now? Also, You might want to consider what to do when the string starts with `'\0'` (empty string).

Comment: Doesn't the read system call return the length?  Then you don't need to search for the terminating 0.

Comment: with what should I compare in order to check if the string gets nul-terminated (END OF STRING)   @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Vazquez-Abrams